# Facing Difficulty With NSThread While Trying To Animate Label

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I'm very new to IOS programming and i have doubt with NSThread.
My problem is, i have a **UILabel** in my view and i want to hide and make it visible Successively after every 5 second.
For this purpose i've used **NSThread** as below.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(animate) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

    -(void) animate
    {
        while(animateLabel){
               [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];
                if(label.hidden){
                    NSLog(@"Label is hidden");
                    [label setHidden:NO];
                }else
                 { 
                    NSLog(@"Label is vissible");
                   [label setHidden:YES];
                   }


  }
}
```

Now i'm getting **"Label is hidden" and  "Label is vissible"** Successively in log after every 5 seconds. But my label is not getting hide.

I did with **NSTimer** and it's working.

But, what is the problem with above code ?. If no problem with this code, Why NSThread couldn't do ?

Comment: I think this might be a thread-safety issue; from what I understand the UIKit is **not** thread safe and only the main thread should touch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform this on a main thread instead.

Try this -

```
[NSThread performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(animate) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

since you have while loop

remove sleep and add runloop

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:(NSDate*)]
```

Comment: As my code is in while loop.. Application UI will become in-active.

Comment: Edited my answer. This should wrk now

Answer (score 0):

UI can be changed only by main thread. instead of creating new thread you can use selector 
 try this -

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(animate) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0 ];
```

Comment: My Idea was to use performSelector (if it calls in main thread)  instead of creating new thread and then notify to main thread to simply for UI Modification

Answer (score 0):

My Bad, didn't read that you purposely intended to do it with NSThread, here's how to do it with NSTimer anyway:

If you create NSTimer from the main thread you don't even need to deal with threading safety-issues.

declare an NSTimer in the Header file so you can reach it in case you want to cancel it or something (I'm also assuming your label is named 'mainLabel' and is declared properly):

```
NSTimer *labelVisibilityTimer;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSTimer *labelVisibilityTimer;
```

in your implementation file, properly synthesize the Timer and initialize it with the method that will trigger the visibility change.

```
@synthesize labelVisibilityTimer;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    self.labelVisibilityTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(toggleVisibilityOfLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)toggleVisibilityOfLabel{
    mainLabel.hidden = !mainLabel.hidden;
}


- (void)viewDidUnload{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.labelVisibilityTimer = nil;
}

- (void) dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [labelVisibilityTimer release];
}
```

Comment: i mentioned in my question that "I Did with NSTimer", as similar to your code.